# ng-bind-html doesnt work for Input tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind, ngsanitize

I am trying to store a HTML inside a scope variable and then use it in template view. When I was reading how to do this in angular, I came across `ng-bind-html`. In that I've noticed that when I bind html tags with `<a>`, `<strong>`, etc.. it works. But I am unable to add `<input>` tags to it.

**Meaning, this works:**

```
$scope.myHtml = '<strong>This is <a hreaf="#">Something</a></strong>';
```

Template:

```
<p ng-bind-html="myHtml"> </p>
```

**But this doesnt work:**

```
$scope.myHtml = '<input type="text" />';
```

Template:

```
<p ng-bind-html="myHtml"> </p>
```

The above is just a simplified sample for demonstration purpose only. My question is:

**1) Does  tags not work with ng-bind-html directive?**

**2) If not, how can I html bind a input tag so I can insert it inside the view?**

Comment: It probably doesn't, html is sanitised before it is inserted, and I would guess input is considered unsafe. Why do you need to do this. It looks messy and I'm sure there is a better way using templates or directives.

Comment: I am actually trying to use this inside a complicated directive that constructs the html tags for input based on the attribute selection and then use this inside a template that it is getting via `$http get`.

Comment: Are you using the `compile` function in that directive?

Comment: yeah.. it compiles it at the end.

Comment: when I was searching now, I just happened to come across `$sce.trustAsHtml()` function. I think it may work. Gonna give that a try and will update soon. :)

Comment: Ok. If not I still think you could do this without having to use `ng-bind-html` or similar by declaring the compile function in the directive's directive definition object and mutating the template in there.

Comment: aha...thats interesting. i will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: hi @EdHinchliffe when you suggested to declare the compile function in the directive's directive definition, did you refer to something like  wickY26 example below?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I didn't mean exactly how @wickY26 has suggested, but it sounds like you found a solution that works for you now :)

Comment: yeah.. @wickY26 's directive method is the one I am using atm. Since that was a directive's directive definition, I thought thats what you had suggested too. Either ways I am glad I didint go with the `ng-bind-html` for this in the end. :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you are getting $sce:unsafe error...

this means you should use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` but newer version of angularjs does not include this directive anymore so you shoud use $`sce.trustAsHtml()` like this...

```
$scope.trustedInputHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text" />');
```

but this way you cannot bind scope variables to your html so best way is writing a directive which can be replace with `ng-bind-html-unsafe`...

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/F8TqVWfHF3uNunVTUVRH?p=preview) for both $sce and directive examples...

Comment: LOVING IT! I am going to test out your working sample. Thank you for this awesome example. I will be back with an update once I test it in my app.

Comment: @blackops_programmer see my update as well if you do not want to create a custom directive for that...

Comment: Thank you heaps for your answers. Using `$sce.trustAsHtml()` before `ng-bind-html` did work. However, in the end I went with the directive approch for this after taking your suggestion as well as taking EdHinchliffe and Whisher's recommendation on this. And the better part is I dont even need to use the sanitize module to get this to work. Thank you so much. It took me several hours today searching on this! I am happy that there is a clean method to achieve this. Your Plunker sample above helped a lot. Much obliged! :)

Comment: The directive @wickY26 talked is just the `compile` directive right here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile renamed ^^

Comment: Wow! just what I was looking for to solve my problem here: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221962/using-angularjs-ng-repeat-to-generate-table-with-dynamic-html-elements). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I would keep the stuff you insert in its own template and use ng-include (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Having a angular template (template.html) with the contents:

```
<strong>This is <a href="#">Something</a></strong>
```

You can include it with

```
<p ng-include="template.html"></p>
```

This results in sth like

```
<p ng-include="template.html"><span class="ng-scope"><strong>This is <a href="#">Something</a></strong></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular selectively sanitizes certain HTML tags with **ng-bind-html**

so if you want all the tags you should use **ng-bind-html-unsafe** instead

but watch out of XSS attacks !

### BTW

It's far better to follow the @Ed Hinchliffe piece of advice

Comment: I think the `ng-bind-html-unsafe` doesnt work in the latest version anymore.

Comment: I checked it out with the 1.2.16 version and it works