# How to escape string for use in input field using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a situation where I need to escape the following string to be used as the preloaded value for an input field. I would usually use data-bind-html but this doesn't show in the input box.
Here is my string:

```
"Website Design &amp; Development"
```

and currently my input field is as follows:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="group.name" required>
```

When I use mg-model, it populates the input form value fine, but when I use the following:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-bind-html="group.name" required>
```

Am I doing this correctly or can someone see where I am going wrong? I would ideally like a way to escape the html entities in the controller before it gets shown in the view but I am not sure if this is possible?
Thanks

Comment: You missed a bit.. "When I use mg-model, it populates the input form value fine, but when I use the following:".. then what?

Comment: No I haven't. Check the question again... When I use 'ng-bind-html' the input box doesn't get populated

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-bind-html doesnt work for Input tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808062/ng-bind-html-doesnt-work-for-input-tags)